# Minimum of Numpy Array Ignoring Diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

I have to find the maximum value of a numpy array ignoring the diagonal elements.

np.amax() provides ways to find it ignoring specific axes. How can I achieve the same ignoring all the diagonal elements?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use a mask

```
mask = np.ones(a.shape, dtype=bool)
np.fill_diagonal(mask, 0)
max_value = a[mask].max()
```

where `a` is the matrix you want to find the max of. The mask selects the off-diagonal elements, so `a[mask]` will be a long vector of all the off-diagonal elements. Then you just take the max.

Or, if you don't mind modifying the original array

```
np.fill_diagonal(a, -np.inf)
max_value = a.max()
```

Of course, you can always make a copy and then do the above without modifying the original. Also, this is assuming that `a` is some floating point format.

Comment: What is the difference between a[ mask ].max() and np.max( a[mask] )?

Comment: @Gerald No difference that I'm aware of.

Comment: You can also just use `a[~np.eye(*a.shape, dtype=bool)].max()`.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is to use NumPy's `as_strided` to push the diagonal to the first column and then slice it off:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
b = np.arange(0,25,1).reshape((5,5))
n = b.shape[0]
out = np.max(as_strided(b, (n-1,n+1), (b.itemsize*(n+1), b.itemsize))[:,1:])
```

For `b`, which looks like:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

the above code produces

```
23
```

Where the argument to `np.max` is the shifted view on `b`:

```
In [7]: as_strided(b, (n-1,n+1), (b.itemsize*(n+1), b.itemsize))
Out[7]: array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
               [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
               [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
               [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

so that:

```
In [8]: as_strided(b, (n-1,n+1), (b.itemsize*(n+1), b.itemsize))[:,1:]
Out[8]: array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
               [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
               [13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
               [19, 20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

Comment: Wow, that's cool. Probably faster than using a mask for large arrays.

Comment: Can this be extended to batched matrices (i.e. where there are some preceding dimensions)?

Comment: @user76284 This might work for an array of `m` `n`x`n` arrays: `np.max(as_strided(c, (m,n-1,n+1), (c.itemsize*n*n, c.itemsize*(n+1), c.itemsize))[:,:,1:], axis=(1,2))`: for a better answer, you should ask a new question I think.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random

# create sample matrix
a = numpy.random.randint(10,size=(8,8))
a[0,0] = 100
```

which looks like

```
array([[100, 8, 6, 5, 5, 7, 4, 5],
   [4, 6, 1, 7, 4, 5, 8, 5],
   [0, 2, 0, 7, 4, 2, 7, 9],
   [5, 7, 5, 9, 8, 3, 2, 8],
   [2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 7, 8, 1],
   [6, 6, 7, 6, 0, 6, 6, 8],
   [6, 0, 1, 9, 7, 7, 9, 3],
   [0, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4]])
```

```
# create mask
mask = np.ones((8,8)) 
mask = (mask - np.diag(np.ones(8))).astype(np.bool)
```

which looks like:

```
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Then

```
# calculate the maximum
out = np.amax(a[mask])
```

Output:

```
9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here looking for way to find the **minimum values along an axis** while ignoring the diagonal, then you could use `numpy.where` to replace the diagonal with the array max and find `min` along an axis:

```
row_mins = np.where(np.eye(*a.shape, dtype=bool), a.max(), a).min(axis=1)
```

For `max` along axis change `max` by `min` and vice versa:

```
row_maxs = np.where(np.eye(*a.shape, dtype=bool), a.min(), a).max(axis=1)
```

---

Another option is to add the array max to the values on the diagonal and find `min` along an axis (subtract the max for `max`):

```
row_mins = (a+np.diag([a.max()]*len(a))).min(axis=1)

row_maxs = (a-np.diag([a.max()]*len(a))).max(axis=1)
```

---

**Example:**

For array:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

The output of

```
out = np.where(np.eye(*a.shape, dtype=bool), a.max(), a).min(axis=1)
```

is

```
array([ 1,  5, 10, 15, 20])
```

Answer (score 0):

[Copying this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394377/minimum-of-numpy-array-ignoring-diagonal#comment113625831_29394823) as an answer:

```
a[~np.eye(*a.shape, dtype=bool)].min()
```